# File Name in ASP.NET Response Buffer

Tags: c#, asp.net

When doing something like this:

```
Response.Clear();

Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
Response.Flush();
```

The downloaded file name is "Default.aspx". How can I change it to something like "a.mp3"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var cd = new ContentDisposition 
{
    FileName = "file.mp3"
};
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

[ContentDisposition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.aspx) is a convenient class that allows you to set the [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt) header in a friendly manner, without knowing the internals of the HTTP protocol. Of course you could always set the header manually if you prefer:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.mp3");
```

Comment: I would only add, if you're going for the manual way and the filename potentially contains spaces and you don't know the HTTP in detail, then you need to quote it: `"attachment; filename=\"file with spaces.mp3\""`.